# Reactjs swiper not starting properly - error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, typeerror, swiper.js

I am using Swiperjs to make a gallery but it 'expodes' the whole app on initialization. If I recall, I copy/pasted the code from their website (https://codesandbox.io/s/fbs9e8?file=/src/App.jsx) and adapted it. I think it is because the initial useState is null, but I dont know how to solve it. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs, Autoplay, Controller, Pagination } from "swiper";
import { Image } from '@chakra-ui/react';
// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/free-mode";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/thumbs";
import "swiper/css/zoom";
import "swiper/css/autoplay";
import "swiper/css/pagination";

import "./galleryStyles.css";

export default function Gallery({ item }) {
    const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null);

    const displayImages = () => {
        return (
            <>
                {
                    item.postImageURLs && item.postImageURLs !== undefined ?
                        item.postImageURLs.map((img, index) => {
                            // console.log(img)
                            return (
                                <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                                    <Image src={`${img}`} />
                                </SwiperSlide>
                            )
                        })
                        : "no pics to show"
                }
            </>
        )
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Swiper
                style={{
                    'height': '25vh',
                    "--swiper-navigation-color": "#fff",
                    "--swiper-pagination-color": "#fff",
                }}
                loop
                speed={400}
                // spaceBetween={10}
                navigation={true}
                autoplay={true}
                pagination={{
                    type: "progressbar",
                }}
                modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs, Autoplay, Pagination]}
                thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}//FIXME: there is s aproblem at initiation that the state is null

                onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
            // controller={{ control: secondSwiper }}
            >
                {displayImages()}
            </Swiper>
            <Swiper
                onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
                autoplay={{
                    delay: 0.01,
                    // disableOnInteraction: true
                }}
                speed={2000}
                loop={true}
                spaceBetween={10}
                slidesPerView={8}
                freeMode={true}
                watchSlidesProgress={true}
                modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs, Autoplay]}
                className="mySwiper"
                style={{
                    'maxHeight': '8vh'
                }}

            >
                {displayImages()}
            </Swiper>
        </>
    );
}
```

and the error I am getting is:
[TypeError - click to see the printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OzwD.png)

Comment: You shared `setThumbsSwiper` and `thumbsSwiper` in 2 sliders. Could you please create a new state so that 2 sliders can use them respectively?

Comment: How did you solve this? @Tom

Comment: How did you resolve this, as I'm getting the same issue here

Comment: Hi guys, in the end I wrote the gallery on my own and ditched the library. great to hear @SubhasishNath you solved it. That may help other people!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it :
Just change the

```
thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
```

to

```
thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper && !thumbsSwiper.destroyed ? thumbsSwiper : null }}
```

that's it.